# Share existing post to Facebook app by id/url using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

So in my app I display some Facebook posts from a predefined page. I get the posts from my server (the server gets them from Facebook directly) and this way I avoid using the Facebook SDK.

For each post, I have both the id and the URL and whenever a user presses on a post I open the Facebook app on that given post.

Now I'd like to add the possibility for users to share these posts to their profile pages, but when a user opens a post (on the Facebook app) it doesn't appear any option to share it (only like and comment). Other option would be to use the standard android sharing feature (ACTION_SEND), but whenever I share a post's URL this way the app only shares a picture from that post, not the actual post.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no way to mimic the "share" behavior that exists on the facebook.com website using graph API. The closest thing would be to use the [`link` field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#pubfields) that you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using the link to open the post on the browser. Funny thing is, when I'm opening the page I get a dialog asking if I want to open it in Chrome browser or the Facebook app and if I chose the Facebook app I get a share option.

Comment: That is to be expected. The Facebook app is registered with the mobile platform that it is running on as an app that is capable of handing links that begin with facebook.com, which causes the mobile OS to prompt the user with a dialog that lets them choose which app to open a link with. The fact that the FB app does implement a sharing feature does not mean that it is available through Graph API.

Comment: Is there anyone know why FB doesn't implement this feature?
 I think they intend to make shortage in any UI client tries to compete their website or mobile app !!!

Comment: This is not the place for speculations about why a company may or may not have certain products. You can [suggest](https://www.facebook.com/help/suggestions) to Facebook that they implement this feature, though.