# Share an existing facebook post using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

Currently, I was able to share a new post by following code:

```
FB.ui(
{
  method: 'share',
  href: 'someurl'
}, function(response){ });
```

But, I need to share an existing post in facebook using its "post_id" such that the share count in the original post is increased.
Is this feature supported by facebook javascript sdk ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155366/share-existing-post-to-facebook-app-by-id-url-using-graph-api

Comment: _“such that the share count in the original post is increased”_ – pretty sure that happens automatically, all you need to do is share the post URL.